# How to mock firebase/auth method createUserWithEmailAndPassword and firebase/firestore method addDoc in Redux Toolkit async thunk?

Tags: javascript, firebase, jestjs, mocking, redux-thunk

I'm trying to test redux async thunk using Jest. In this thunk I call two firebase methods, so I want to mock them in my test. But mocked methods return undefined instead of objects specified in the mocked implementation. So mocks are being applied in the process of test execution, but values they should return are somehow ignored. What am I doing wrong?

userSlice.test.js

```
import {registerUser} from '../slices/userSlice';

const mockedСreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = jest.fn();
mockedСreateUserWithEmailAndPassword.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ user: { refreshToken: '123', uid: '321' } }));

const mockedAddDoc = jest.fn();
mockedAddDoc.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ doc: {id: '333'} }));

jest.mock('firebase/firestore', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('firebase/firestore'),
  addDoc: () => mockedAddDoc,
}));

jest.mock('firebase/auth', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('firebase/auth'),
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword: () => mockedСreateUserWithEmailAndPassword,
}));

describe('registerUser thunk', () => {
  it('should register user with resolved response', async () => {


    const dispatch = jest.fn();
    const thunk = registerUser({ 
    name: 'TestName', 
    surname: 'TestSurname', 
    email: 'test@test.com', 
    password: 'testPassword' 
  },
)

await thunk (dispatch, () => {}, () => {});
const [start, end] = dispatch.mock.calls;
expect(start[1].type).toBe('user/registerUser/fulfilled');

  })
})
```

userSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import db, { firebaseApp } from './../../firebase';
import { collection,  addDoc} from "firebase/firestore";

firebaseApp;
const authdata = getAuth();

const initialState = {
  email: null,
  token: null,
  id: null,
  name: null,
  surname: null,
  userDocID: null,
  favorites: [],
  status: null,
  error: null,
};

export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/registerUser',

  async function (data) {
    const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(authdata, data.email, data.password)

    const { name, surname, email } = data;
    const { refreshToken, uid } = user;

    const userRec = {
      name,
      surname,
      email,
      token: refreshToken,
      id: uid,
      favorites: [],
    };

    const doc = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), userRec);
    return {
      ...userRec,
      userDocID: doc.id
    }
  }
)

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,

  extraReducers:
    builder => {
      builder
        .addCase(registerUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          const {
            name,
            surname,
            email,
            token,
            id,
            favorites,
            userDocID,
          } = action.payload;

          state.status = 'resolved';
          state.name = name;
          state.surname = surname;
          state.email = email;
          state.token = token;
          state.id = id;
          state.favorites = favorites;
          state.userDocID = userDocID;
        })
    },

  reducers: {},
});

export default userSlice.reducer;
```